# Using Gradle's Worker API to reduce build time in gradle build task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently i was going through gradle's [Worker API](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/). I think it's great. 
From the docs, it can be used to split task into different independent unit and run them in parallel. Hence this can reduced the build time by X. Also, we can also run independent task using within same projects parallelly. I was able to run two custom tasks from my android project using [Worker API](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/) to run them parallelly which saved me couple of seconds.

I was able to run two custom task in my project parallelly. 
However, i was wondering if we can use the worker api to split the android **Gradle's** **build** task so that we can execute it parallelly ? If possible to split and run the independent components of the build tasks parallelly it will massively reduce the build time.

How can we split the build task into independent component and run them using Worker API. Is this even possible? 
Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle will never run tasks within the same project in parallel, it will only ever run tasks in separate projects in parallel

> I was able to run two custom tasks from my android project using Worker API to run them parallelly

To do this I assume that you explicitly called `Task.execute()` which you should NEVER do. This can break all kinds of things.

The worker API is quite limited since you don't have (legal) access to the `Project` instance so can't call exec(...), fileTree(...), copy(...) or many other useful / fundamental utilities.

The best thing that you can do to benefit from parallel execution is to split your project into multiple modules

Comment: How are we suppose to run two task parallely then ? I have two tasks directly written in build.gradle which download a jar from maven and perform javaexec operation. I want to run these two tasks parallelly. Can you help me do it ? 
Before gradle 4.0 we had annotation @Parallelizable task but with worker api we can get the instance of project so how are we suppose to do any operation?

Comment: Currently, the only option is to have the tasks in separate projects so that gradle can run them in parallel

Comment: However we can run a two task in parallel if we dont need the project instance at all using Worker API

Comment: You can't run two tasks in the same module in parallel. If you want to benefit from Gradle's parallel task execution the tasks must be in separate modules. This may change in future but I believe its currently impossible to (legally) run two tasks in the same module in parallel

Comment: If you look at the WorkExecutor documentation : https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/workers/WorkerExecutor.html
It says clearly `Safe execution of multiple tasks in parallel`. The way i have achieved making two task of the same project to run in parallel is submit two different runnable implementation to WorkExecutor(). Are you suggesting this is illegal way of doing it ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, perhaps if two tasks in a module use worker api AND don't depend on each other then their workers can execute in parallel? If you call `someTask.execute()` then it's the "illegal" usage I'm referring to. If its just plain old java in a `Runnable` then it's perfectly legal (and it seems I was wrong)